# Tengo error al llamar este método en el Context context

Tags: java, android

Tengo este método.

```
public static void BD_backup(Context context) throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    final String inFileName = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
    File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), DATABASE_NAME + "_" + timeStamp);
    Log.d(TAG,"inFileName: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

Lo llamo así `BD_backup(Context context);` pero me dice que no es correcto, error en el `Context context`.

Comparto el link de  donde  me estoy basando.

https://www.hell-desk.com/acceder-al-fichero-de-una-base-de-datos-sqlite-en-android/

Comment: Puedes compartir la excepción que ves durante la depuración?

Comment: La verdad se me hace raro que ni siquiera uses un `try catch`, tu código es un sensible a excepciones para comenzar si la ruta es la indicada o q la ruta no encuentre nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Editado] Quizás estas llamando mal al método, si estás dentro de una Activity se utiliza getContext(), intenta con:

`public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) { 
          super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
          try { 
                BD_backup( context); 
              }
          catch (IOException e) { 
                 e.printStackTrace(); 
                 } 
     }`

Comment: No  estoy en  un  activity, es código en mi Helper, les  comparto en link   donde  me  estoy basando.                                                            https://www.hell-desk.com/acceder-al-fichero-de-una-base-de-datos-sqlite-en-android/

Comment: y con "getApplicationContext()"? el helper tiene context?

Comment: Al  poner  BD_backup(Context  context)  me  muestra el siguiente error                   Error:(62, 31) error: ')' expected
Error:(62, 39) error: illegal start of expression

Comment: podrias adjuntar la línea de código donde da el error ?

Comment: este  es mi linea de  cóigo.                                                                                                 public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        try {
            BD_backup(Context context);  // aquí me   muestra el error
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: prueba con         public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) { super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION); try { BD_backup( context); // aquí me marca el erroe } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }

Comment: ya  está   solucionado